# I disagree with the closure of my question

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Does a per-device firewall configuration standard exist or is in the process of being specified?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63095/does-a-per-device-firewall-configuration-standard-exist-or-is-in-the-process-of)

I disagree with my question being closed as off-topic, because while the community is about professional networking, my question was about whether standards exist / are in the work to make the tools available in professional networking available to consumers by for example packaging device-specific firewall rules so that they can be easily imported by consumer grade routers.

Somehow, the people who answered assume I want to achieve isolation goals on a current home grade router that I own or want to ask about how to set up isolation myself. *I don't*.

I came to this community because I assumed that more people will be familiar with recent developments in networking and might know about some things that are in the works.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Directly from your original question:

> this is not a question about how to accomplish this, but whether it
>   exists.

What you ask for already exists. Businesses do that all the time. What you are really asking is if the manufacturers of consumer-grade equipment will add those features to their equipment, but we simply cannot answer that. You need to ask those manufacturers. What they sell is what people are willing to pay for. The features require added software and hardware, and most consumers are not willing to pay more for consumer-grade devices simply for those features. Anyone can easily buy business-grade equipment to do that, but it costs more because the added software and hardware to perform those functions costs more to produce. Also, the consumers would need to know how to configure such things; it is no longer a simple plug-and-play.

The bottom line is you are asking for speculation as to what may happen in the future, but speculation and guessing are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are first and foremost asking a yes-no question. Does this exist as a standard? No. Is someone going to propose it as a standard? I'm not aware of any, but I can't read the minds of ~7bil people. All one can say is there are no *current* standards track proposals for such a thing.

However, at the same time, *enterprise* level hardware has had this capability -- in various forms -- for many years. (guest vlan, port isolation, etc.) You don't see this in consumer gear because they're cheap and almost always *unmanaged*. (with the exception of "ap-isolation" being fairly common in wireless gear.) If you want to know how to do this on your hardware, we need to know your exact hardware.

In the end, your question leads to speculation, which is not allowed on any stack.